# MVCFoolProof does not work with AutoMapper in my Unit test project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

While my main application works fine, the unit test project is giving following error, when I try to execute "Mapper.AddProfile" method in initialiation of unit test project.

The type initializer for 'Foolproof.ContingentValidationAttribute' threw an exception.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have not used MVC 2.0.0.0 anywhere in my main project, and test project as well. Both these projects refer to MVC 4.0.0.0

what could be the possible issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the MVCFoolProof project has a reference to MVC2. See here: [CodePlex Source Code](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94877#1188719) - you could try pulling the source down and compiling it yourself against MVC4.

Comment: If it references MVC 2, then how it works fine in my main application which uses MVC 4 only? This problem is occurring only from Unit Test project.

Comment: Do you have a reference to MVC4 within your unit test project? If not, try adding one to see if that fixes it. You might also try clearing out the temporary ASP.NET files and then rebuilding

Comment: yes, I have MVC 4 reference in my unit test project, and that doesn't work.

Comment: Also, I checked source code of FoolProof project, and could notice it is referring ASP.NET MVC 2.0.0.0.. how can I change my test project to change binding to target 4.0.0.0

Comment: How did you add the reference to MVCFoolProof? Via Nuget? Downloaded from CodePlex? Built from the original source?

Comment: I realized why it works in main project.. its because the binding redirects configured in web.config takes into account.. but the same is not true for app.config in unit test project....

Comment: You could try downloading [the source] (http://foolproof.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94877) and building it yourself rather than using the nuget package. A bit of a pain but it would get you past this issue

Comment: Ignore me then :) - well spotted

Comment: now, the next thing would be to know how to set binding redirect in app.config file.. because, as far as I know they aren't considered! not sure, but they should be !!